# How to stop password autofill in HTML forms

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

How can I stop Chrome and Firefox from autofilling password fields if I have set `autocomplete="off"` and it still does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After almost a year of fighting this problem, I found through trial and error that Chrome and Firefox use absolute desperation to fill in these fields for you. The HTML tag `autocomplete="off"` is completely and almost criminally ignored (this is such a security concern I can't even..)

Here's a trick that should work: if you have a field that has anything to do with an email address (label, placeholder, name, ANYTHING imaginable) you must not place the password field under it. Place a hidden field or just re-organize your inputs so that passwords never follow emails. If these thirsty browsers even sense a "password-like" field under your email field (and presumably "account" field?) they will try and fill that second input field with your password.

Utter insanity requires equally stupid solutions.